# It create file in local dir, if i open local dir file, it will open normally, but when i put to download by base64 code it turn corrupted

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

Well, my code is from my API in python. Initialy i try to do by base64 code, passing the base64 string and creating the file to download at php. It dowload the file, same size as original, but when i try to open the pdf/xlsx file, it shows msg that is corrupted.

The base64 code API:

```
@goals.route('/getPdfB64',methods=['GET'])
def getPdfB64():
    c = canvas.Canvas("C:/Report.pdf", pagesize=landscape(A4))
    c.drawString(300, 300, f'TEST')

    pdf = c.getpdfdata()
    pdf_b64 = base64.b64encode(pdf).decode('utf-8')

    data = {
        "code" : 200,
        "value" : {
            "base64" : pdf_b64
        }
    }
    return jsonify(data)
```

The PHP that receives the file:

```
<?php
$file = json_decode(sendAPIRequest("GET", "localhost:5000/getPdfB64",[]));
$file = base64_decode($file->value->base64);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file));

echo $file;

exit;
```

It do the download, but always corrupt. Well, to know if my original file is corrupted, i make a line to save the file at local dir and then, pass file dir by API to download at PHP and it works for pdf.

API:

```
@goals.route('/getPdfB64',methods=['GET'])
def getPdfB64():
    fileDir = "C:/Report.pdf"
    c = canvas.Canvas(fileDir, pagesize=landscape(A4))
    c.drawString(300, 300, f'TEST')
    c.save()

    pdf = c.getpdfdata()
    pdf_b64 = base64.b64encode(pdf).decode('utf-8')

    data = {
        "code" : 200,
        "value" : {
            "base64" : pdf_b64,
            "dir" : fileDir
        }
    }
    return jsonify(data)
```

PHP:

```
$file = json_decode(sendAPIRequest("GET", "localhost:5000/getPdfB64",[]));
$file = $file->value->dir;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

The problem at this point is: it works for pdf, but i want it by base64 string, because i don't want to save local files... then i try to get base64 of saved file and try to pass it by API to discover if this way base64 code will go.

API:

```
@goals.route('/getPdfB64',methods=['GET'])
def getPdfB64():
    fileDir = "C:/Report.pdf"
    c = canvas.Canvas(fileDir, pagesize=landscape(A4))
    c.drawString(300, 300, f'TEST')
    c.save()

    with open(fileDir, "rb") as file:
        pdf = file.read()

    pdf_b64 = base64.b64encode(pdf).decode('utf-8')

    data = {
        "code" : 200,
        "value" : {
            "base64" : pdf_b64,
            "dir" : fileDir
        }
    }
    return jsonify(data)
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = json_decode(sendAPIRequest("GET", "localhost:5000/getPdfB64",[]));
$file = base64_decode($file->value->base64);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file));

echo $file;

exit;
```

And it continue corrupted. But i open the local file manualy it opens normal.

Comment: Please reduce to a minimal reproducible amount of code.

Comment: It's already reduced... maybe u think it's too much code because i post all things i've tryed... but is reduced

Comment: Why would you even send the json back? Why would not you send the file as is w/o base64 encoding? Try debugging by comparing hashsums (i.e. md5) at py and at php sides.

Comment: Well, let's go..

@Jared i tryed with base64 encoding, but the same problemsm occurs, corrupted file.

Comment: @KJ i think i'll make a button to donwload with href "/

Solution: i made it generate file locally and make a button to download with href

Comment: I mean if you don't have to wrap the binary data in some sort of structure containing additional data - like JSON in your case - you don't have to encode the data at all. Just send it as is.